# Unable to use sub account with Google Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I needed to create a script that uploads the resulting screen shots to google drive.

I was hoping I could just auth in as my google user, but that seems... harder? So I abandoned that tact. Next I moved onto service accounts. This works fine (now) for my service account, but when I attempt to specify a user ($auth->sub) I get "Unauthorized client or scope in request.".

```
function buildService($userEmail) {
  $DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'notsupplied@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'pathtofile.p12';

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
    $key);
  $auth->sub = 'myuser@gmail.com';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_Service_Drive($client);
}
```

I'd love to abandon the service account and just auth with my regular google user if thats just as easy. Or solve how (in the api settings maybe?) I can ensure myuser@gmail.com can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh_token is the key here. In a webbrowser use this link to approve your google user:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=lso&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fauth%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Foauth2callback%26access_type%3Doffline%26client_id%3D<CLIENT_ID>%26hl%3Den%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D34eac985232ba748&btmpl=authsub&hl=en&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline
```

which will return a URL like https://www.example.com/oauth2callback?code=

Then post code=&client_id=&client_secret=&redirect_uri=&grant_type=authorization_code to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

This will return a "refresh_token" parameter. Save this. Very important. If you don't get one you have to go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions to revoke permissions from your app.

After you get the refresh token you're good to go:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$token = $client->refreshToken('<YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN>');
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```